# Can´t show message after form submit with header("location:")

Tags: php

I've search the forum for the same situation that I have but still couldn't find the solution. It's probably a piece of cake but I can't figure it out why my $_GET[] doesn't work.

I've created a product page and when I add something to the cart I want to display a message. I've made it work with the url in the form action but then my cart counter in the header stops working properly. 
If it's possible I don't want to add any extra in the url like a "?success" because then it just keeps adding ?success to the url if I add more to the cart, that works in action but not with header() ?

Here is my code for the product page:

```
<?php include_once '../header.php';

$message = "";
$product = New Product;
$cart_data = [];


// if the variables are set - run the following statement
if(isset($_POST["addtocart"])) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE["cart"])) {

      // Removes backlashes and dont replace previous item, gives every item a new row.
      $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['cart']); 
      $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
    }

  // Returns the productid and Size in the array
  $item_list = array_column($cart_data, 'ProductsId');
  $size_list = array_column($cart_data, 'Size');

  // Returns the value if the statement is true
  if(in_array($_POST["ProductsId"], $item_list) && in_array($_POST['selectedSize'], $size_list)) {

    // A foreachloop that repeats the array value of the selected key variable. 
    foreach($cart_data as $keys => $values) {
      if($cart_data[$keys]["ProductsId"] == $_POST["ProductsId"] && $cart_data[$keys]["Size"] == $_POST["selectedSize"]) {
        $cart_data[$keys]["quantity"] = $cart_data[$keys]["quantity"] + $_POST["quantity"];
      }
    }
  }
    else {

      $item_array = array(

        'Img'             => $Img = filter_var($_POST["Img"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),        
        'ProductName'     => $ProductName = filter_var($_POST["ProductName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
        'Size'            => $Size = filter_var($_POST['selectedSize'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
        'ProductsId'      => $ProductsId = filter_var($_POST["ProductsId"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
        'Price'           => $Price  = filter_var($_POST["Price"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
        'quantity'        => $quantity = filter_var($_POST["quantity"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
      );

      $cart_data[] = $item_array; 
    }

    $item_data = json_encode($cart_data);
    setcookie('cart', $item_data, time() +(3600),'/');
    header("location: product-detail.php?product=".$_GET['product']."?success");
  }

  if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
    $message = "Varan lades till i varukorgen";
  };

var_dump($message);
?>

<main id="product-content">
  <section>
  <form method="post" name="cartCount" action=""> 
  <!-- product-detail.php?product=<?php echo $_GET['product']; ?> -->
      <?php if(isset($_GET['product'])) {
        $product->ProductsId = $_GET['product'];
        $product->ProductId = $_GET['product'];
        $product->ProductsId = $_GET['product'];
      } else {
        $product->ProductsId = $_POST['ProductsId'];
      }
        $result = $product->get_product();
        $test = $product->get_productvariation(); 
      while ($row = $result->fetch()) { ?>   

      <div class="product-card-detail">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
          <img class="product-image" src="../<?php echo $row['Img'];?>" >
          <input type ="hidden" name="Img" value="<?php echo $row['Img'] ?>">
          <?php $results = $product->get_images();
          $Images = $results->fetch();
          if(isset($Images['Image'])) { ?>
          <img class="product-image" src="../<?php echo $Images['Image'];?>">
          <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div class="product-details-text">
          <h2 class="title"><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></h2>
          <input type ="hidden" name="ProductName" value="<?php echo $row['ProductName'] ?>">
          <span class="price"><?php echo $row['Price'];?> SEK</span>
          <input type ="hidden" name="Price" value="<?php echo $row['Price'] ?>">
          <span class="select-title">Storlek</span>

          <select class="size" name="selectedSize"> 
            <?php while ($sizeRow = $test->fetch()) { ?>
              <option>
                <?php echo $sizeRow['Size']; ?>
              </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>

          <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1"  />

          <input type="submit" class="addtocart-btn"  name="addtocart" value="Lägg i varukorgen"/>
          <div><?php echo $message ?></div>

          <input type ="hidden" name="ProductsId" value="<?php echo $row['ProductsId'] ?>">
          <span class="title-description">Beskrivning</span>
          <p class="description"><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>              
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
<?php include_once "../footer.php";?>
```

I've made a test page that works exactly as expected so I can only think that is has to be something about the url?

Test code:

```
<?php
$message ="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  header("location: index.php?success");
} 

if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
  $message = "hello";
  }

  var_dump($message);
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input text name="name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<?php echo $message ?>
</form>
```

Glad if anyone can see why it doesn't work!

Comment: So just to clarify - your code works as expected, and the only problem your having is unwanted text being added to the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a mistake:

```
header("location: product-detail.php?product=".$_GET['product']."?success");
```

See the above line and notice that you are appending param `success` with `?`.
Make it `&` as:

```
header("location: product-detail.php?product=".$_GET['product']."&success");
```

Comment: OMG so simple!!!! Now I feel so stupid! It works of course! And it also solved the problem with adding more ?success to the url :D

Comment: just ask here if you face any problem. We're here to help you. :)